# How to get create a histogram over time?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm trying to visualize how a distribution changes over time -- each vertical slice should be the distribution at that timestep.

I want it to look something like this (there are two such curves/temporal-histograms here).

[image]

The closest I've found is this seaborn time series, but I want the distribution or at least the min, mean, and max -- this band is a confidence interval, which I can't use (it's also prohibitively slow).
https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html

[image]

---

Update:

Here's a snippet to product some sample data.

```
import numpy as np
num_timesteps = 20
samples_per_timestep = 100
timesteps = np.arange(num_timesteps)

def get_std(t):
    return t if t < num_timesteps//2 else abs(num_timesteps - t)

samples = np.stack([np.random.normal(t, get_std(t), samples_per_timestep) for t in timesteps])
```

`samples[t]` is a sample of the ditribution a timestep `t`.  The distribution starts as constant (std = 0), widens, then narrows again.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing! Plotting distributions (that can represent uncertainty or population characteristics) would be an immensely useful feature for me.

I found this blog: https://minimizeregret.com/post/2020/06/07/rediscovering-bayesian-structural-time-series/ which has a few very nice similar plots. It looks like matplotlib, but probably a lot of custom code.

Comment: I wrote a feature request for Seaborn: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3101

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and took quite a few detours, but this is most definitely possible!

#### Imports

We need to import matplotlib, NumPy and Pandas.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

#### Input data

I assume you have the data as a Pandas Series, with the time/step on the index and the values as values.

| Step | Wealth |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 7.89338 |
| 1 | 7.50838 |
| 1 | 2.00948 |
| 1 | 8.74963 |

I load my data from a pickle (in the format specified above):

```py
wealth = pd.read_pickle("wealth.pickle")
```

You can download a ZIP with this pickle file here: [wealth.zip](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/files/9833164/wealth.zip).

#### Aggregate the data to percentiles

This part is a bit ugly. We first define a partial NumPy function for each percentile we want to calculate:

```py
# Define functions to calculate percentiles
def q1(x):
    return x.quantile(0.01)

def q5(x):
    return x.quantile(0.05)

def q25(x):
    return x.quantile(0.25)

def q50(x):
    return x.quantile(0.50)

def q75(x):
    return x.quantile(0.75)

def q95(x):
    return x.quantile(0.95)

def q99(x):
    return x.quantile(0.99)
```

*If anyone reading this has a better/cleaner way to aggerate this, please let me know!*

Note we use [numpy.quantile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html), because (in my case) it works better with the data in the series, but [numpy.percentile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) should be equivalent.

The data now needs to be grouped by the index (`level=0`), and then aggerated using the functions defined above:

```py
w_agg = wealth.groupby(level=0).agg([q1, q5, q25, q50, q75, q95, q99])
```

And now `w_agg` looks like this:

| Step | q1 | q5 | q25 | q50 | q75 | q95 | q99 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | -3.2311 | 0.759751 | 3.2881 | 6.03641 | 8.43206 | 11.9663 | 15.4515 |
| 2 | -3.22888 | -1.15079 | 3.13756 | 6.41804 | 8.43206 | 12.7269 | 15.4515 |
| 3 | -5.31614 | -1.91156 | 3.22287 | 6.54126 | 8.77544 | 14.644 | 15.5798 |
| 4 | -5.64095 | -2.52143 | 2.65959 | 6.22455 | 9.40699 | 14.6545 | 15.9647 |

#### Plotting

Now we can start with the plotting. Aside from the regulars, we're using [`matplotlib.filbetween`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) for this.

We create a figure, and then start with the widest percentile range: From 1 to 99. Then we draw 5 to 95 on top of that, then 25 to 75 on top of that and finally the median as a line.

Play a bit with the `alpha` and `color` values to make it look nice!

```py
# Create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Add the bands to the axes
ax.fill_between(x=w_agg.index, y1=w_agg["q1"], y2=w_agg["q99"], alpha=0.3, color="tab:blue")
ax.fill_between(x=w_agg.index, y1=w_agg["q5"], y2=w_agg["q95"], alpha=0.3, color="tab:blue")
ax.fill_between(x=w_agg.index, y1=w_agg["q25"], y2=w_agg["q75"], alpha=0.3, color="tab:blue")

# Plot the median as line
ax.plot(w_agg.index, w_agg["q50"], '-', color="tab:blue")

# Add title, legend and plot
ax.set_title("Distribution of wealth between population over time")
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Wealth")
ax.legend([f"{n}% distribution" for n in [99, 90, 50]] + ["Median"], loc="upper left")
fig.tight_layout()
```

#### The result

For my dataset, this was the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** So I asked about this in the Seaborn repository, and this can be [way simpler](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3101#issuecomment-1286873815) using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/).

Here's an example:

```python
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri").query("region == 'parietal'")

p = so.Plot(fmri, "timepoint", "signal")
for tail in [25, 10, 5, 1]:
    p = p.add(so.Band(), so.Perc([tail, 100 - tail]))
p.add(so.Line(), so.Agg("median"))
```

Which will result in this plot:

[image: Timeseries distribution plot]

You can read more about it in [Statistical estimation and error bars](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars).

This is a lot less work and better scalable. Hope it helps!

Comment: I think we have two types of distributions in mind -- your independent variable is scalar at each timestep (see my update above).

Comment: I think you're missing an `import seaborn.objects as so`